# SSIS packageformat 1 and 0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

What does SSIS packageformat 1 and 0 stand for ? According to the [official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181582.aspx) there is only 2 and 3.

Where
*A value of 2 indicates that the package is saved in the SQL Server 2005 Integration Services format.
A value of 3 indicates that the package is saved in the SQL Server 2008 Integration Services format.*

I have them stored on a SQL2008R2 server's MSDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of queries around the web (for example [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=1446)) whereby 0 means '2005' and 1 means '2008'. I think really the '2008' is 'not 2005'. Certainly if you look in an MSDB on 2012 there are rows with '1' where the actual XML contains a `PackageFormatVersion` of 6.

The 2/3/6 are the values which go into the `<DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">6</DTS:Property>` bit of the XML of the actual package.

I think that MSDN doc page is just wrong.